# Jenkins error with plugin bitbucket branch source plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

Since the last plugin update, all my builds are failing, but I did'nt change any configuration.
I tried to rollback to last version of plugin but the problem persists.

It seems like BitbucketStatusNotificationPlugin is trying to access some Mercurial class...

The project is a multibranch pipeline. 
The issue is also referenced on the official JIRA of Jenkins project [JENKINS-46296](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46296)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the output :

```
 Started by user Olivier
 Checking out git REPO_URL
 into /var/jenkins_home/workspace/TaaS_API_TaaS_develop-HDR4FYYRLEPSYBGEYT6L5UEWPW5HVQDT5PW7ZBCJ6VTGPTYLU6OQ@script to read Jenkinsfile
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url 
timeout=10
 Fetching without tags
 Fetching upstream changes from REPO_URL
 > git --version # timeout=10
 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket pass
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress 
 +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
 Checking out Revision 5fa34124eb6be5ab7242633a97cced7de4e7af5e (develop)
 Commit message: "Finish team"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5fa34124eb6be5ab7242633a97cced7de4e7af5e
 > git rev-list 5fa34124eb6be5ab7242633a97cced7de4e7af5e # timeout=10
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCMSource$MercurialRevision from class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications
 at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.getHash(BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.java:124)
 at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.sendNotifications(BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.java:104)
 at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.access$000(BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.java:54)
 at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications$JobCheckOutListener.onCheckout(BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.java:14
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:127)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:130)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:120)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:263)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a version incompatibility between your plugins.

Make sure you update all of the required dependencies to at least the required versions. The minimum required versions of dependencies for the latest version of the plugin can be located on the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin).

For older versions, the easiest place to get this information I've found so far is probably the pom file [e.g. version 2.2.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source-2.2.4/pom.xml).

Before version 2.0 of the mercurial plugin, the type `MercurialSCMSource.MercurialRevision` was [package private](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/commit/fc225569f9de83bc21aa43806223b95e1d34fc45) (not visible to other packages/plugins).

The latest version of the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin (2.2.6) declares a dependency on at least version 2.0 of the mercurial plugin. I'm not sure which versions are declared for the versions you are using, but it seems that mercurial 2.0 has been [required since at least version 2.2.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/commit/a4c6bf39b83168ff62fc622bd4084ef90cf810c0#diff-20fbcbbed2581147ccff1c5a32449b49R124) of the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin.

Even if you aren't using mercurial, the code/classes are still required.

Comment: that was the point, I've updated all the jenkins plugins, even Jenkins itself, and the issu was gone away.